# Search for a particular object in a list

Tags: c#, list, contains

I have a list of objects and I want to see if a particular object is in this list.  When I use the `Contains()` or `IndexOf()` methods on the list i get incorrect results however, since this uses the `Equals()` method of the object which is not what i need.  I want to find a particular instance and not an object that seems to have equal property values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to match the references, you can use:

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(item1, item2))
    ...
```

to force it to compare references instead of using `Equals()`

Or:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(item=>ReferenceEquals(item, target));
```

(See the [MSDN Documentation for List.FindIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.)

Comment: OP has made very much clear that he does not want to check if items are equal by reference, he just want to check if a `System.Type` of item already exist in the list !

Comment: I think he hasn't... He said *"I want to find a particular **instance** and not an object that seems to have equal property values."* Nowhere does he say anything about types.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the hashcode?

```
list.where(w => w.GetHashCode() == object.GetHashCode())
```

Comment: I think he wants the references to be equal, not the objects' contents